# Why is my Foreach only outputting the first bit of data?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, foreach

Reasonably new to bots and C# in general. I'm trying to output all the links inner text matching `//a[@class='featuredBox` but it's only outputting the first bit of data.

When I debug, it does, in fact, have loads of values attached to it, so I'm confused as to why this isn't outputting them all?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.jasminedirectory.com/computers/companies/");

    var headingNames = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='featuredBox']").ToList();

    foreach (var item in headingNames)
    {
        botOutput.Text = item.InnerText + "</br>";
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there multiple items in `headingNames`?

Comment: Yep, there is. Quite a few.

Comment: Or you can do it with Linq instead of a `foreach` loop: `botOutput.Text = string.Join("</br>", headingNames.Select(item => item.InnerText)) + "</br>";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a `+` before your `=`. Currently it looks like you're just overwriting the `Text` property on each loop, it sounds like you want to append each match instead.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.jasminedirectory.com/computers/companies/");

  var headingNames = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='featuredBox']").ToList();

  foreach (var item in headingNames)
  {
    botOutput.Text += item.InnerText + "</br>";
  }
}
```

Alternative approach:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.jasminedirectory.com/computers/companies/");

  var headingNames = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='featuredBox']").ToList();
  botOutput = headingNames.Select(name => name.InnerText).Aggregate((current, next) => $"{current}</br>{next}") + "</br>";
}
```

Comment: Odd though that it's only the "first" entry getting shown, rather than the last. Typically when this happens you only see the last item.

Comment: Ah! That's solved the problem. Very frustrated with myself as I only learnt that the other day. Thank you!

Comment: @gunr2171 Agreed, but this seemed probable nonetheless

Comment: Glad to hear it, @GerryHodson!

Comment: As @zero noted, you probably want to use a StringBuilder to build the string, and then assign it to the text box's text.  Doing string concatenation in a loop is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You are constantly replacing (instead of appending).  Do this instead:

```
foreach (var item in headingNames)
{
    botOutput.Text += item.InnerText + "</br>";
}
```

Probably worth noting if `headingNames` is large you should use a `StringBuilder` or you're generating needless GC pressure because `string` is immutable.